# How to create a temporary table using LIKE without the source table partition in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

How to create a temporary table using LIKE when my source table has partitions?

For example,
Table t1 is

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(30)
)
    PARTITION BY RANGE (id) (
        PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1000001),
        PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2000001),
        PARTITION future VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

Attempting to create temporary table temp_t1

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_t1 LIKE t1;
```

Throws the error:
`SQL Error [1562] [HY000]: Cannot create temporary table with partitions`

I know one can use `CREATE ... AS SELECT...`, however, I'm looking for `CREATE ... LIKE ...` solution if possible.

P.S. I don't need the temporary table to have any partition. But need the field structures intact if possible. The mysql user for doing this operation will not have `CREATE` and `DROP` `TABLE` permissions, it will only have `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` permission along with a few other operational specific permissions.

Comment: MySQL can't create temp tables with partitions.

Comment: SOme suggestions here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210869/creating-a-temporary-copy-of-a-table-with-partitions

Comment: I don't need temporary table to have partition. Can it still be done?

Comment: look at the answers in the link I gave above, thats what the link is for

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly, however that answer does not satisfy my need. The user by which this operation would be done will not have permission to create and drop table. That user will have create temporary table permission and a few other operation specific permissions.